# Как обмануть Google Maps, что мое устройство имеет GPS-приемник?

Tags: железо, android

У меня есть рутованное устройство без GPS. Оно получает местоположение через блютуз с другого устройства и подставляет его в систему с помощью `mock locations`. Но когда я запускаю `Google Maps` я получаю сообщение

> "Turn-by-turn navigation is only available on devices with GPS
>   hardware"

Возможно ли обмануть `Google Maps` (и другие навигационные программы, которые проверяют наличие GPS-приемника в устростве), что у моего устройства есть GPS-приемник? Программно, или изменив какой-нибудь конфиг в операционной системе, ну или любым другим способом.

Answer (score 2):

Для ответа нужно разреверсить библиотеку, и посмотреть, какая проверка дает такое условие. Реверс гуглить по словам `smali` и `apktool`

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего Google карты проверяют наличие GPS с помощью метода [hasSystemFeature](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature(java.lang.String)).

Можно попробовать добавить эту фичу (android.hardware.location.gps) на устройство программно. Пример как это сделать можно найти [тут](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1787972).